# How to Create a single shape from multiple shape in Elm playground?

Tags: elm

I have a view function which is

view : Computer -> Memory -> List Shape

In the list of shape I want to add a Box function which will return a box which consist of multiple shape So I need to convert them from multiple shape to single shape to use in the view

how to do this in elm-playground ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `group` function is doing exactly this.